# Shaperange(1) versus Shaperange() insecurity

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Sorry for another newbie question. I need help understanding the difference in
Shaperange(1) versus Shaperange()
I try to use the .GroupItems.Count. When I address it directly it's all fine. But when I select two shapes and use Shaperange(1) I would get an Object error 424 Object Required

```
Debug.Print ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange().GroupItems.Count 'this is fine and gives the correct number


With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
    Debug.Print .Name 'this is fine and gives the correct name
    Debug.Print .GroupItems.Count 'Object required error 424

End With
```

Comment: Is there more code? When I try to run your sample, the first line raises an error "Run-time error '-2147188160 (80048240)': ShapeRange (unknown member) : Invalid request. Command cannot be applied to a shape range with multiple shapes."

Comment: Oh thank you @John Korchok. Actually that is weird - I shortened the code to the minimum which creates the error. Of course there is more code. Should I post the whole code here?
Funnily I get no error but a correct group item count on line one. 

Also: When I try to tag this, powerpoint-vba is the suggestion I get from stackoverflow -- but braX edited that into two tags (powerpoint and vba) - can someone help me understand that please

Comment: @JohnKorchok https://www.screencast.com/t/nmufqikJFZP works for me? But only with one group selected as a Debug. 
In the code I let the user select a picture and the group. Then I decide which is the group and put it in a variable

Dim oShpBox As Shape
If .ShapeRange(1).Type = msoGroup Then
      Set oShpBox = .ShapeRange(1)
End If

Here I hit the problem so I went back to a barebone 
With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1) 
and got the same problem with  .GroupItems